# Easy word problem but am I working it too hard?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

A friend of mine gave me this problem:

> A man who walks at a constant speed goes to his barn 30 miles away
>   with a 2 mph wind pushing against him. After arriving at the barn he
>   remembers he forgot something, so he walks back, but this time the 2 mph
>   wind is working in his favor. When he reaches his house, the entire
>   trip so far has taken 8 hours. What is the man's normal walking speed (i.e. if there is no wind)?

I set it up this way:

$30 = (r-2)t_1 = (r+2)t_2$ where $t_1 + t_2 = 8$

$30/(r-2) + 30/(r+2) = 8$

$30(r+2) + 30(r-2) = 8(r+2)(r-2)$

$2r^2 - 15r -8 = 0$

$r = -1/2, 8 \implies r = 8$

Did I overlook something really obvious or did this actually require the quadratic formula to solve?

Comment: Your work is correct.  You can solve the quadratic equation $2r^2 - 15r - 8 = 0$ by factoring, so you do not actually need the Quadratic Formula.  What you do need to do is solve the quadratic equation you obtained.

Comment: If you'll forgive my going off-topic, I'm very curious to hear where your friend came upon this problem. The numbers are so outrageous that it sounds like parody, or a psychology question designed to catch [nonsense] detection: His barn is _$30$ miles_ away. Oops, he forgot something (maybe the key to the barn, or the $100$-lb bale of hay for the horse, or his pack of Marlboro cigarettes), so he spent _$8$ hours_ doing nothing but walking (or rather, trotting, doing an eight-minute mile) for _sixty miles_. I love it!

Comment: The injection of parody is my own; I changed a few details as to make it harder to Google, but a family friend of mine asked me for some help on her (young) son's homework question. I was surprised that I had to resort to the quadratic formula to solve it, and I was going crazy thinking I had overlooked something for such a simple problem because I was unable to find a faster way to do it (some other constraint that removes the quadratic part somehow).

Comment: You do get a quadratic in cases like this.  You haven't overlooked anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming a $2$ mph wind changes his walking speed by $2$ mph.  That seems unreasonable to me.  I would hang my hat on the constant speed and say he covered $60$ miles in $8$ hours, so walked $7.5$ mph.  The way you read the problem you have solved it correctly.  He walks $6$ mph outbound for $5$ hours and $10$ mph inbound for $3$ hours.  In any case he walks very fast.

Comment: `That seems unreasonable to me` My thoughts exactly. It astonishes me that they wouldn't specify that assumption in the question. Me reading that, I would simply give the answer: "Not enough information to accurately solve the question".

Comment: Unfortunately it seems various textbooks give completely idiotic, unanswerable questions, while the answer key gives an answer based on simplistic (and patently wrong) assumptions. (In this particular case, the question _is_ answerable under reasonable assumptions, namely the ones that give the answer $7.5$. But I fear that's not what the answer key says.)

Comment: In this case the answer is $8$. You're supposed to assume that the 2 mph wind changes the speed by a full 2 mph.